# Slow computer processing

Tags: windows-xp, performance, processing

I run a 1.66 Ghz Duo Core with 512 RAM. I had rebuilt my OS about a month ago, started it as Windows XP SP2. then I updated it to Windows XP SP3 and installed all the latest updates about 90 of them. Since then my computer is processing slow, taking more time than usual to load on boot up, slower gaming applications etc.

I've been defragmenting on weekly basis, cleaning up temporary files etc. I guess if it is because of the updates that I've installed then how does it make your computer run slow than normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you do not have enough memory to really run Windows XP well. Your are probably doing a lot of memory swapping to the hard drive, causing you slowness. New service packs, and a lot of (necessary security) updates can often make it worse.

I consider 1GB the minimum to run XP well, and 2GB to run Vista/Windows 7 well. I have had many people, who I know and have helped personally, change their minds about buying a new computer after simply upgrading the RAM (and cleaning the viruses out, in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

Viruses and malware are usually the culprit.. follow these easy steps.. no need to upgrade your pc and spend money. it helped me alot too.. its not just cleaning files but also doing some tweaking in the performance configuration of the windows. You need to delete the bloatware, change the settings of notification, removing unwanted apps and disabling startup apps.

https://step-diychannel.tumblr.com/post/660627460767006720/speed-up-your-windows-for-free-and-very-easy-steps

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.